# How to add event listener to newly added elements?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm adding list items with delete buttons to list and old items can be deleted but newly added cannot.

I tried to add an event listener to new list items' delete buttons additionally but I couldn't.

```
var deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".delete");
deleteButtons.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", deleteItem);
});

function deleteItem(e) {
  e.target.parentElement.parentElement.removeChild(e.target.parentElement);
}
```

I watched Brad Traversy's dom videos on Youtube and tried to make delete items part on my own. Commented codes are Brad's codes. In my codes, I tried to select delete buttons and add them, eventListener. With `deleteItem` function I can delete old list items but cannot delete newly added. Because newly added list elements' delete buttons have not event listener. My question is "In Brad's version, how newly added to list items have event listener and in my version newly added delete buttons have not?"

Codes: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JQxGpv

Comment: Use event delegation instead

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance. I think this article explains well: https://medium.com/@bretdoucette/part-4-what-is-event-delegation-in-javascript-f5c8c0de2983